# No puedo instalar Mysql

Tags: mysql

El instalador me devuelve ese error .

> No compatible serves were found. You'll need to cancel this wizard and install one .

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/518313/edit) para agregar más información como sistema operativo, versión de MySQL y cómo estás tratando de instalar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que desinstales MySQL y después de desinstalarlo instales:

Visual C++

Una vez instales ese requisito, ya puedes volver a instalar MySQL